# requestAnimationFrame callback принимает неправильное время

Tags: javascript, анимация

Итак проблема в следующем:

Коллбек, который я отправляю в функцию `requestAnimationFrame` в итоге получает
неверное время. Первый параметр функции `callback` должен получать значение
`performance.now()` в начале выполнения этого коллбека, но в итоге выходит, что
переменная `start = performance.now();`, которую я объявил до использования
`requestAnimationFrame(callback)` больше, чем переменная `time`. Чего, в принципе, быть не может.

Использую браузер *Chrome* последней версии. Скрин:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто-то сталкивался с подобным? Как исправить?

Вот необходимый код. Переменная duration в данный момент равна 3000. Но
это никак не влияет на проблему, она может быть хоть -10000000.

```
const start = performance.now();

const makeFrame = time => {

  let timeFraction = (time - start) / duration;

  if (timeFraction > 1) {
    timeFraction = 1;
  }

  const progress = timing(timeFraction);
  draw(progress);

  if(timeFraction < 1) {
    requestAnimationFrame(makeFrame);
  }

}
//запрашиваем первый кадр
requestAnimationFrame(makeFrame);
```

Comment: ...приложи код...

Comment: Трюк с определением performance.now() помог. Спасибо. И все же очень странное поведение параметра коллбека.